# Laravel 5 - Saved data overwritten

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am having an issue with data being overwritten.  I have a Document Model and a DocumentData Model.  A Document can have many DocumentData.
So I have a data capture form, and in my create function if I output the request I get something like the following

```
array:8 [▼
  "_token" => "UHTN66xH4ChHpaxWAt4hWYFfpwUyjo6EunLp2iuV"
  "whatData" => "rgfterter"
  "whoData" => "tertertertert"
  "startDate" => "28-04-2016"
  "deliveryDate" => "30-04-2016"
  "whyData" => "wefrwerwe"
  "howData" => "rwerwerwer"
  "filePath" => array:2 [▼
    0 => UploadedFile {#30 ▼
      -test: false
      -originalName: "image.png"
      -mimeType: "image/png"
      -size: 788038
      -error: 0
    }
    1 => UploadedFile {#31 ▼
      -test: false
      -originalName: "image2.png"
      -mimeType: "image/png"
      -size: 1091127
      -error: 0
    }
  ]
]
```

What I then need to do is create a Document

```
$document = new Document();
$document->projectId = $project->id;
$document->name = 'Test Document';
$document->save();
```

And then do the documentData using the above data.  DocumentData essentially has a key/value, where the key is the input label and the value is the inputted data.
At the moment I am doing this

```
$documentData = new DocumentData();
$documentData->documentId = $document->id;

foreach ($inputs as $key => $value) {
    if($key !== '_token' && $key !== 'filePath') {
        $documentData->key = $key;
        $documentData->value = $value;
    }
    $documentData->save();
}

$fileString = "";
if (Input::hasFile('filePath')) {
    $files = Input::file('filePath');

    foreach($files as $file) {
        $file->move(public_path('uploads'), $file->getClientOriginalName());

        $fileString .= public_path('uploads') . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $documentData->key = 'File Path';
        $documentData->value = $fileString;
        $documentData->save();
    }
}
```

The Document is created fine, but I am only getting one row for DocumentData - the last uploaded file path.  So it appears that the other rows are being overwritten.
How can I make sure all inputs are recorded correctly within my database?

Thanks

Comment: 1. `$documentData->documentId = $document->id;` is unecessary if you set-up relationships correctly; you can do: `$documentData->document()->saveMany()` - 2. I recommend [reading the Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#introduction) because you're not that far off.  3. I don't recommend you looping through input data and setting properties, be more explicit would be better.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question properly, but are you trying to make multiple instances of `DocumentData`, if so then you're going about it in the wrong way. Your final snippet of code doesn't create a new `DocumentData` entry in the db per uploaded file, it will just keep writing to the same entry which is why you see the last uploaded file only. You need to new up a new instance within the for loop for it to create multiple instances. In any case you should, as ash recommended look up relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make things easier set up some relations in your Eloquent models. As I understand, a `Document` can have many `DocumentData`s so you can set up a  **one-to-many** relationship for this by firstly adding the relationship method in `Document` class:

```
public function documentData()
{
    // you should include the full namespace here
    return $this->hasMany(App\DocumentData::class);
}
```

and then you can set up the other side of the relation on the `DocumentData` class:

```
public function document()
{
    // again, you should include the full namespace here
    return $this->belongsTo(App\Document::class);
}
```

Now you can access and create using these relationship methods!

I'm going to rewrite out (what I assume is) your controller action here with some adjustments, let me know if you're not following.

```
public function storeDocument(Request $request)
{
    // create new document
    $document = new Document();
    $document->name = 'Test Document';
    // you could probably set up a relationship for this too!
    $document->projectId = $project->id; 
    $document->save();

    // grab the uploaded files
    //we can use this to loop through and create a DataDocument per uploaded file
    // this assumes uploading a file is required, otherwise it won't work!
    $uploadedFiles = $request->file('filePath');

    // loop through each file
    foreach($uploadedFiles as $file) {
        if ($file->isValid()) {
            // upload file logic
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileName = uniqid() . '.' . $extension; // give the file a unique name
            $file->move(public_path() . '/uploads', $fileName);

            // create our new DocumentData related to our Document 
            // using our documentData() relationship
            $document->documentData()->create([
                'whatData'     => $request->get('whatData'),
                'whoData'      => $request->get('whoData'),
                'startDate'    => $request->get('startDate'),
                'deliveryDate' => $request->get('deliveryDate'),
                'whyData'      => $request->get('whyData'),
                'howData'      => $request->get('howData'),
                'filePath'     => public_path() . '/uploads' . $fileName,
            ]);

            // finish up!
            dd($document); 
            // dd() so you can see what you've created,
            // of course you should probably return redirect here
        }
    }

}
```

Things to note:

1. There may be some mistakes in the code as I haven't tested it,
   please make a comment if that's the case and you need help
2. If this answer works for you that's great, but it may be more
   important to understand why your initial approach didn't! You
   weren't creating a new entry in your DB for each file you uploaded
   plus some other minor issues.
3. Get well acquainted with Eloquent and relationships, they're really
   powerful and will save you a lot of headache even if you can  grasp
   some of the basics it will make your DB interactions much simpler!

Happy coding!